# Why is sudo very slow (more than 30minutes) to display initial password prompt for a domain account?

Tags: ssh, login, sudo

I am hoping someone can help me figure out why 'sudo' takes longer than 30mins (on average) to display the initial password prompt when using a domain account.

This problem occurs even after a reboot, but it works fine when using a local account.

quick summary:

- I have 3 brand new Linux VMs running in a VMware vSphere 6.7 environment -> problem occurs on all of them
- each VM was built using the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server iso
- all package updates have been applied.
- each VM is joined to a windows active directory domain
- the windows user account is a member of sudo'ers
- there is no other software installed (basically, it's just the bare minimum packages required to join with the Windows AD domain)

Things I have tried thus far:

1. the '/etc/hosts' file contains an entry for 127.0.1.1 and includes the hostname and fully qualified name (all lowercase), e.g. '127.0.1.1  myserver myserver.domain'
2. checked / confirmed hostname in terminal matches exactly
3. checked DNS -> it seems fine? It has 3 nameservers configured - all are valid.
4. deleted the homedir of the domain user account and let it be recreated by PAM auth

Please advise any troubleshooting steps that I should try?

Thanks!